# Programación Lineal (PL)

Tags: linear-programming

quería ver si me pueden ayudar en plantear el modelo de Programación Lineal para este problema.

Sunco Oil tiene tres procesos distintos que se pueden aplicar para elaborar varios tipos de gasolina. En cada proceso requiere mezclar crudos en el desintegrador catalítico de la compañía. Ejecutar el proceso1 durante 1 hora cuesta 5 dólares y se requieren 2 barriles de crudo 1 y 3 barriles de crudo 2. El producto luego de ejecutar el proceso 1 por una hora es 2 barriles de gasolina 1 y un barril de gasolina 2. Efectuar el proceso 2 durante una hora cuesta 4 dólares y requiere un barril de crudo 1 y 3 barriles de crudo 2. El resultado de correr el proceso 2 por una hora es 3 barriles de gasolina 2. Ejecutar el proceso 3 durante 1 hora cuesta 1 dólar y se requieren 2 barriles de crudo 2 y 3 barriles de gasolina 2. El resultado de correr el proceso 3 por una hora es 2 barriles de gasolina 3. Todas las semanas se podrían comprar 200 barriles de crudo 1 a 2 dólares el barril y 300 barriles de crudo 2 a 3 dólares el barril . Toda la gasolina producida se podría vender a los precios siguientes por barril: gasolina 1, 9 dólares; gasolina 2, 10 dólares; gasolina 3, 24 dólares. Plantee un modelo de PL que maximice las utilidades. Suponga que solo se dispone en la semana de 100 horas de tiempo en el desintegrador catalítico.

---

Translation (by non-native speaker)

I wanted to see if you can help to specify the linear programming model for this problem.

Sunco Oil has three distinct processes that can be applied to produce various types of gasoline.  Each process requires mixing crude oil in the company's  catalytic cracker.

Process 1: Run for 1 hour, costs 5 dollars, and requires 2 barrels of crude 1 and 3 barrels of crude 2. The product after running process 1 for an hour is 2 barrels of gasoline and one barrel of petrol 2.

Performing process 2 for an hour costs 4 dollars and requires a barrel of crude 1 and 3 barrels of crude 2. The result of running the process 2 for an hour is 3 barrels of petrol 2.

Running process 3 for 1 hour costs  1  dollar and requires 2 barrels of crude 2 and 3 barrels of petrol 2. The result of running process 3 for an hour is 2 barrels of gasoline in March.

Every week you could buy 200 barrels of crude 1 at 2 dollars/barrel and 300 barrels of oil 2 at 3 dollars/barrel. All gasoline produced can be sold at the following prices per barrel: petrol one, 9 dollars; petrol 2, 10 dollars; gasoline 3, 24 dollars.

Pose a PL model that maximizes profits. Suppose you can only run the catalytic cracker for 100 hours per week.

Comment: sabes escribir el función que quieres maximizar? y sabes escribir las limitaciónes? creo que este problema quiere que uses el algoritmo Simplex. por ejemple, tenemos el función que queremos maximizar: dice que la cantidad de crudo $i$ que hacemos es $x_i$, y entonces tenemos que maximizar $\text{maximise } 9x_1+10x_2+24x_3$

Comment: (¡lo siento por mi español!)

Comment: Busca la informacion del "Simplex Method"

Comment: I translated it to English if you want to remove the hold.

Answer (score 1):

### Variables:

- $x_1=$ cuantos barillos de crudo 1 compras.
- $x_2=$ cuantos barillos de crudo 2 compras.
- $p_1=$ horas de proceso 1
- $p_2=$ horas de proceso 2
- $p_3=$ horas de proceso 3
- $g_1=$ cuantos barillos de gasolina 1 vendes
- $g_2=$ cuantos barillos de gasolina 2 vendes
- $g_2'=$ gasolina 2 que no vendes pero consumes en proceso 3
- $g_3=$ cuantos barillos de gasolina 3 vendes

(Es possible  eliminar unas variables, pero es más facil comprender con todas)

### Condiciones:

- $x_1\ge0, \ldots, g_3\ge0$
- $p_1+p_2+p_3\le 100$ (horas que el desintegrador catalitico está disponible)
- $x_1\le 200, x_2\le 300$ (maximum comprar crudos)
- $ 2p_1+p_2= x_1$ (consumo del todo el crudo 1)
- $ 3p_1+3p_2+2p_3= x_2$ (consumption del todo el crudo 2)
- $ p_2= 2g_2'$ (consumo del gasolina 2)
- $g_1 = 2p_1$ (producción del gasolina 1)
- $g_2+g_2' = p_1+3p_2$ (production de la gasolina 2)
- $g_3 = 2p_3$ (producción de la gasolina 3)

### Utilidades:

$$t = \underbrace{9g_1+ 10g_2+24g_3}_{\text{vende}}-\underbrace{5p_1-4p_2-1p_3}_{\text{cuanto cuesta el proceso}}-2\underbrace{x_1-3x_2}_{\text{compra crudo}}$$

Comment: Wow, ich finde ihre Lösung prima und ihr Spanisch auch.